# How would I separate a string by commas becoming new lines in my just detail view and not in my database? Is it even possible?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The thing is, that I'm trying to make my details page look better, so it is not so blank.
Currently it comes out just as a long string, separated by commas.

[this is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lupDr.jpg)

[this is how i want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5YMB.jpg)

In the model it looks like this: `public string UNCPath { get; set; }`

And in the view it looks like this:

```
<dd class="col-sm-10">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UNCPath)
</dd>
```

Is it possible to get the string  separated only in html? or do I need to do it in my model and/or controller? And can you give me something to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better solution, if you do that in `Html`, i tried the following code, it's work fine :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
@foreach(string item in Model.UNCPath.Split(','))
{
   <label style="font-weight:100">@item</label>
   <br/>
}
</div>
```

if you use `Bootstrap` the `font-weight` of the label is `bold(700)`, use `100` instead.

**Second solution**

1 - Model : add list of string like :

```
public List<string> UNCPathList { get; set; }
```

2 - Controller : split your string like :

```
UNCPathList = "tikala disham AERO2018(\\BEBRS) (O:) (R), tikala disham PROD3(\\SUNS)(Q:) (R), tikala disham PRODUKTI(\\BEBRS)(P:) (R)".Split(',').ToList()
```

3 - View :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
@foreach(string item in Model.UNCPathList)
{
   <label style="font-weight:100">@item</label>
   <br/>
}
</div>
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: The first one worked out just great. thanks. I cant really do the second solution because i have entries in my database already. But thanks for the quick and easy answer. :)

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result in my index view? https://jsfiddle.net/dtnuhm87/

Comment: yes, maybe like this : ``@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @foreach (string splitedPath in item.UNCPath.Split(','))
                {
                    <label style="font-weight:100">@splitedPath</label>
                    <br />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }``

Comment: yeah, this worked out just great :) now I can use this template in other fields.